# Unable to Obtain Table Information in Enterprise Architect - MySQL

Tags: mysql, odbc, enterprise-architect

I'm using Sparx Enterprise Architect version 9.2 to import a database schema from a MySQL database using the ODBC connection.  When I test the ODBC connection using the ODBC Data Source Administrator (Windows 7), the connection tests successfully.  I'm using the MySQL ODBC 5.1 driver.

In Enterprise Architect when I try to use this ODBC connection to import the schema I get a message saying, "Unable to obtain table information".

Am I missing something?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

The information provided by PsiX is helpful and relevant, but not the piece I was missing.  The missing info can be found [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/projects_and_teams/setupapostgresqlodbcdriver.html), which applies even though it's talking about PostgreSQL (because it's being accessed through ODBC either way).  Here is the pertinent information from the link above:

> If you are using a 64-bit operating system:
>
> • Enterprise Architect
> requires 32-bit ODBC drivers to connect to a repository through ODBC;
> to set up the ODBC configuration on 64-bit clients, run the 32-bit
> ODBC Data Source Administrator from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
>
> • You can quickly load the correct 32-bit ODBC Data Source
> Administrator by selecting Tools |  ODBC Data Sources in the
> Enterprise Architect menu bar

This piece of information was, unfortunately, omitted in the instructions for setting up Enterprise Architect for MySQL.  (Too bad I hadn't noticed the option under Tools previously.  Some of us have to do things the hard way!)  Thanks again for the info provided by PsiX.  It may be just what the next person needs so I'll give it an up-vote.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Did you use the correct ODBC driver?

32 vs 64 bit is relevant here.

Did you check the two checkboxes as described in the installation of the driver?
(Select the Return matched rows instead of affected rows and Allow big result sets checkboxes.)
See [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/8.0/projects_and_teams/setupmysqlodbcdriver.html) for a detailed description

Comment: Hi PsiX, I installed the 64-bit ODBC driver version 5.1.13.  Yes, I checked the two check boxes. I have a meeting in a couple of minutes, but I'll try again in a bit.  Should I be using the 32-bit driver even though I'm running 64-bit Windows 7?

Comment: I've tried both the ANSI and Unicode versions of the 64-bit driver.  The 32-bit driver doesn't even show up in the ODBC configuration utility.  So far, I keep getting the same error message of "Unable to obtain table information".

Comment: @MylesRip: Yes, you should use the 32bit driver even if you are on 64bit Windows.

Comment: Deinstall the 64bit version and install the 32bit one:
http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-ODBC/5.1/mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.13-win32.msi